# How can I prevent certain keys (e.g. Super/Win) from being passed through to a qemu guest?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, qemu, virt-manager

I am running a Windows 10 guest under Linux using qemu / virt-manager.  All of my WM shortcuts in X use the super (windows) key.  I don't really need that key for anything inside the Windows VM.  Is there any way I can hold back certain keys / key-combinations on the host side, while still passing everything else through to the guest when it has focus?  Then I could, for example, use super-n to switch to virtual screen #n in my X environment, without first extracting myself from the VM.